# Write in a database with Android

Tags: android, database, post, android-volley, kotlin

I am trying to write in a database with the library Volley using Kotlin and when I try nothing happened. I used [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to see if there is a problem from the server and all is okay. According to me the problem comes from this part of my code:

```
val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "myURL",

                Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            try {
                val obj = JSONObject(response)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        },
        object : Response.ErrorListener {
            override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }) {
    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
    override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
        val params = HashMap<String, String>()
        params.put("name", name)
        params.put("genre", genre)
        return params
    }
}
    VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
```

Thank you a lot to try to solve my problem !!!

Comment: Yeah sure ! But Is is normal that when I click on the button I have no Toast.maketext which appear ??? I feel like if the last line does not exist it is really strange !

Comment: Someone can help me ?